# SharePoint 2010: Claims based authentication from an MVC web app

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, claims-based-identity

I am using MVC4 and need to access and modify data in a SharePoint site. I found this:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh147177.aspx

Sample code here:
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Remote-Authentication-in-b7b6f43c

Very interesting, but the sample code is for Windows Forms and the problem is it opens a windows form to ask for credentials.

What I need is a way to achieve the same thing but in a web app.. sample code for either MVC or web forms would be fine. I can't seem to find anything on the web about this, so does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found exactly what I needed here:
http://www.wictorwilen.se/Post/How-to-do-active-authentication-to-Office-365-and-SharePoint-Online.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Can you query the SharePoint site using AD authentication? Or is it very remote? If so, you can use the app pool identity to authenticate against the SharePoint web service.

Answer (score 0):

I've built an STS using MVC3 that provides authentication services for SharePoint. This great [Paraesthesia article](http://www.paraesthesia.com/archive/2011/02/01/working-with-windows-identity-foundation-in-asp-net-mvc.aspx) helped me adapt the sample STS starter code to run as an MVC controller.

It's a good place to start. If you have more specific questions I can probably answer those too.